# Is a perfect space necessarily T1?

Tags: general-topology

I'm reading a book that makes the following definitions:

1. A point $x$ in a topological space $(X,\tau)$ is an isolated point if $\{x\}\in\tau$;
2. If $S\subseteq X$, then the set of all limit points of $S$, $S'$, is the derived set of $S$;
3. If $S'=S$, $S$ is a perfect set; if $S=X$, the topological space $(X,\tau)$ is a perfect space.

After these definitions, there are a series of problems, all of which I solved rather easily. The last one is the one I have trouble with:

> Let $(X,\tau)$ be a perfect space and $A$ a dense set in $(X,\tau)$. Then $A$ has no isolated points.

There was another answer to this problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2749349/open-dense-subset-of-a-perfect-space) but they seem to assume that perfect spaces are $T_1$. My question is whether this is actually the case, at least in the way they are defined here? The book makes no explicit mention of assuming $(X,\tau)$ is $T_1$, and neither did it ask me to prove anything like that. Maybe that's part of the proof for this exercise?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As you can see in that question and answer, with the definitions you have given, the statement is not true. You need some extra assumption in order to make the statement true under that assumption (for instance $T_1$).

Comment: Alright, I suppose it really is just a missing assumption. Thank you, I will reattempt the exercise assuming $(X,\tau)$ is $T_1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll add an answer to remove this from the unanswered queue.

As Andreo stated in [their question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2749349/29059), the topological space $(X,\tau)$ given by
$$X = \{a, b, c, d, e\}\quad\text{ and }\quad \tau = \{\emptyset, \{a, b, c, d, e\}, \{b, c, d, e\}, \{b, c\}, \{d, e\} \}$$
is perfect, but it is clearly not $T_1$ because, for instance, the singelton set $\{b\}$ is not closed (as its complement $\{a,c,d,e\}$ is not open).

Therefore, in order for the statement in your question to be correct, some extra assumption must be imposed (for instance $T_1$).